# Recursively searching for a string in a list of characters

Tags: python, recursion

I have a problem to solve which is to recursively search for a string in a list (length of string and list is atleast 2) and return it's positions. for example: if we had `ab` with the list `['a','b','c']`, the function should return `'(0,2)'`, as `ab` starts at index `0` and ends at `1` (we add one more). 
if we had `bc` with the same list the function should return `'(1,3)'`.
if we had `ac` with the same list the function should return `not found`. 

Note that I'm solving a bigger problem which is to recursively search for a string in a matrix of characters (that appears from up to down, or left to right only), but I am nowhere near the solution, so I'm starting by searching for a word in a row of a matrix on a given index (as for searching for a word in a normal list), so my code might have `char_mat[idx]`, treat it as a normal list like `['c','d','e']` for example. 
Note that my code is full of bugs and it doesn't work, so I explained what I tried to do under it.

```
def search_at_idx(search_word, char_mat, idx, start, end):
if len(char_mat[idx]) == 2:
    if ''.join(char_mat[idx]) == search_word:
        return 0,2
    else:
        return 'not found', 'not found'
start, end = search_at_idx(search_word, char_mat[idx][1:], idx, start+1, end)
return start, end
```

The idea of what I tried to do here is to find the base of the recursion (when the length of the list reaches 2), and with that little problem I just check if my word is equal to the chars when joined together as a string, and return the position of the string if it's equal else return not found 
Then for the recursion step, I send the list without the first character, and my start index +1, so if this function does all the job for me (as the recursion hypothesis), I need to check the last element in the list so my recursion works. (but I don't know really if this is the way to do it since the last index can be not in the word, so I got stuck). 
 
Now I know that I made alot of mistakes and I'm nowhere near the correct answer,I would really appreciate any explanation or help in order to understand how to do this problem and move on to my bigger problem which is finding the string in a matrix of chars.

Comment: What do the start and end parameter mean?

Comment: Why are you dealing this first problem recursevly? checking if a string is inside a list could be done without recursion

Comment: @bilke It's for a homework, Loops are not allowed, I feel like this is my chance to understand recursion more but I've been of thinking and trying for like two days now and none come true.

Comment: @LukasSchmid They mean where the word is found, for example if I'm searching for 'hd' , in the list ['a','b','h','d'], I would get start = 2 (index of h), and end = 4 (the index of 'd' +1). I'm sorry if I wasn't clear I translated it and tried to explain it in my words.

Comment: @Pwaol is the pattern "ab" always length 2?

Comment: @bilke Yes, the input string is at least of length two. it can be more for example 'abc', in list ['a','b','c','d'] would return , '(0,3)'

Comment: @Pwaol you mean (0,2) ? since the "c" is on 2nd index?

Comment: @bilke I know it's a little weird, but the question wants it to be with a plus one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thrown together a little example that should get you a few steps ahead

```
char_mat = [['c', 'e', 'l', 'k', 'v'],]
search_word = 'lk'

def search_at_idx(search_word, char_mat, idx, start=0):
    if len(char_mat[idx]) < len(search_word):
        return 'not', 'found'
    if ''.join(char_mat[idx][:len(search_word)]) == search_word:
        return start, start+len(search_word)
    char_mat[idx] = char_mat[idx][1:]
    start, end = search_at_idx(search_word, char_mat, idx, start+1)
    return start, end 

print(search_at_idx(search_word, char_mat, 0))
```

To point out a few errors of yours:

- In your recursion, you use `char_mat[idx][1:]`. This will pass a slice of the list and not the modified matrix. That means your next call to `char_mat[idx]` will check the letter at that index in the array. I'll recommend using the debugger and stepping through the program to check the contents of your variables
- Instead of using start and end, you can always assume that the found word has the same length as the word you are searching for. So the distance you have to look is always `start + len(search_word)`

If you have any additional questions about my code, please comment.

Here's an example for list comprehension if that counts as `loop`hole:

```
foundword = list(map("".join, list(zip(*([char_mat[idx][i:] + list(char_mat[idx][i-1]) for i in range(len(search_word))])))[:-1])).index(search_word)
print((foundword, foundword + len(search_word)) if foundword else 'Not found')
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I got a question about finding the recursion base, I'm still a beginner and I just learnt that I must find the smallest version of the problem, and return accordingly in the base of the recursion, but I don't know why, I just went and said that the smallest case is when the list size is 2, and I returned (0,2), which failed my recursion, could you explain how should my thoughts go about the recursion base? thank you so much for the help again.

Comment: @Pwaol Let's say you want to sort a list. That's pretty expensive if you compare all elements to each other (n^2). But if you split the list in half and both parts in half again until you have only lists of length <2, you can sort them all instantly and patch them together more easily in O(n) over a depth of log(n).

Comment: Text search is a bit more complicated, as the text might overlap the splits, so you have a lot of edge cases. Your example is kind of bad, as recursion usually means you'll run the same function multiple times within your function. If you only call it once, it's usually better to just run iteratively.
Have a look at mergesort/quicksort

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation, I feel like I have a better understanding now, I will go now and try to do a function to search in columns, same idea as this (Slicing didn't work, so I decided to use list(zip(*char_mat)) to have access to my columns. after this I'm going to try to build a recursive function that sends my search function all the indexes of the columns and rows. so I complete the problem, do you think I can code this is a good way of solving the problem? and do you think I can really program these functions with my knowledge?

Comment: It would make a lot more sense with loops, but you'll get there. You might not be quite there yet, but with a bit of googling, I'm sure you can find the necessary tools and snippets

Comment: I have succeeded thanks to you, and the other answer I got, I appreciate everything, what I did is a function that recurse starting from index 0 and stops whenever the index is bigger than my last row in the matrix (luckily the matrix must be square), and with every recursion I call the two functions to search row and column, and then recurse with my index function with index +1, I would be happy if you could tell me what your way might be of doing this problem, just to see how it would be done in the optimal way.

Comment: Another question is about time complexity, this program is O(n^2) according to my calculations, if I'm calling two recursive functions (search row and column), from my index runner function that I think is O(n), what would the overall time complexity be? Sorry for asking alot of questions, I really appreciate everything, thanks again.

Comment: Since your runner is still checking every element whether the word starts there, it still requires O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["a","b","c"]


def my_indexes(pattern, look_list, indx_val):
    if pattern == "".join(look_list)[:2]:
        return indx_val, indx_val+1
    else:
        if len(look_list) == 2:
            return None
        return my_indexes(pattern, look_list[1:],indx_val+1)

print(my_indexes("bc",l,0))
```

Two options:
1.We find the case we are looking for, so the first two elements of our list are "ab", or
2. "a" and "b" are not first two elements of our list. call the same function without first element of the list,and increase indx_val so our result will be correct.We stop doing this when the len(list) = 2 and we didn't find a case. (assuming we're looking for length of 2 chars)

edit: for all lengths

```
l = ["a","b","c","d"]


def my_indexes(pattern, look_list, indx_val):
    if pattern == "".join(look_list)[:len(pattern)]:
        return indx_val, indx_val+len(pattern) # -1 to match correct indexes
    else:
        if len(look_list) == len(pattern):
            return None
        return my_indexes(pattern, look_list[1:],indx_val+1)

print(my_indexes("cd",l,0))
```

Comment: I thought I left a comment but I forgot, Thanks alot for the explanation and the help, your explanation of we have two cases really helped me understand, I appreciate it :)